# Can't browse the iTunes Store after updating iTunes

Tags: windows-7, itunes

I'm consistently having problems connecting to the iTunes store on Win7 x64. The problem appears to develop when I upgrade to a new version; connecting to the iTunes Store (other than, oddly, checking for app updates) results in the bar filling up to about one third/half, stopping there, and a few minutes later delivering a smattering of unskinned HTML and text boxes.

Uninstalling and reinstalling following Apple's instructions (removing each component in order) doesn't help.

Running the diagnostics results in a report saying that it can connect to every server it needs to, but that it's not enabled in Windows Firewall. This is curious, because there's an entry there for it. Disabling Windows Firewall doesn't resolve the problem. I have no other firewalls running. I'm not running a proxy, and I have full connectivity through other programs; I can also download app updates through iTunes and browse the store normally via wifi on my iPhone. It's just browsing the store that's broken.

How can I fix this issue? Last time this happened, uninstalling and reinstalling fixed it. No such luck this time.

Comment: I don't use iTunes, but from your description it sounds like it's failing to contact the servers that host the CSS files that control the layout (as well as other content).  Perhaps check your HOSTS file for addresses that may have been added?  Do you have any kind of web filtering/blocking software enabled?

Comment: Nope; my hosts file is the default (blank except for commented out instructions) and I don't have any filter software. I'm not behind a proxy, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up finding the solution: iTunes was connecting to one of the store servers via the wrong socket.

To fix this:

- Open up a command line as an Administrator. On Win7, type 'cmd' into the search box on the start menu, right-click on cmd.exe, and select 'Run as Administrator'.
- Type: `netsh winsock reset` and press Enter
- Restart your computer.